# Запятая перед "при которых"

Tags: пунктуация

По идее, перед "*который*" часто ставится запятая, однако оппонент считает, что в данном случае "*который*" не дополнение, а часть предложения, неотделимая по смыслу.

Предложение:

**Завязываемся на неподключенный статус, так как помимо 'подключен/не подключен' есть ещё много других статусов() при которых кнопки должны быть видны.**

Answer (score 3):

....есть ещё много других статусов, **при которых** кнопки должны быть видны.

Запятой выделяется придаточное определительное предложение, ПРИ КОТОРЫХ - союзное слово, которое является членом придаточного предложения (обстоятельством).

Можно заменить: есть ещё много других статусов,  **когда** (=при этих статусах) кнопки должны быть видны.

Comment: спасибо за развёрнутый ответ